# how to concat corresponding rows value to make column name in pandas?

Tags: pandas

I have the below dataframe has in a messy way and I need to club row 0 and 1 to make that as columns and keep rest rows from 3 asis:

```
Start Date  2005-01-01  Unnamed: 3  Unnamed: 4  Unnamed: 5  
Dat   an_1  an_2         an_3       an_4        an_5
mt    mt    s            t          inch        km
23    45    67           78         89          9000
```

change to below dataframe :

```
Dat_mt  an_1_mt     an_2 _s    an_3_t      an_4_inch      an_5_km
23       45         67           78         89             9000
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
df.columns=df.loc[0]+'_'+df.loc[1]
df=df.loc[[2]]
df
Out[429]: 
  Dat_mt an_1_mt an_2_s an_3_t an_4_inch an_5_km
2     23      45     67     78        89    9000
```